# How does Meteor.loginWithExternalSystem work internally?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

From my limited usage of Meteor I found out that loginWithExternalSystem method lets user login with Facebook, Google, etc. In this process, meteor creates new user in db if the user is not present already. Does the new user creation from this method follow same steps as in normal account creation? Can we customize the user creation by using callbacks like 
Accounts.onCreateUser(), Accounts.validateNewUser(), etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `accounts-(google, facebook, twitter, etc.)` packages are just shims that fit into the meteor accounts framework. They will crate a normal account for you, and handle authentication, but all the `Accounts.on()` callbacks will work just fine, as well as `Meteor.user()` and `Meteor.loggingIn()` etc.

The only caveat here is that if you use `Accounts.onCreateUser()` you may get different information back in the user object depending on which service you use. Thye are pretty standardized but there are sometimes extra fields provided by each login service.

Comment: Thank you Brett for the answer. Is there any way to pass additional custom params that I want on user object to the loginWithExternal method?

Comment: It can be done. I just saw the documentation. Thanks for the help. I am able to resolve the problem :)